# WebStorm/IntelliJ does not associate TypeScript file type

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, webstorm

I cannot get IntelliJ/WebStorm to associate a ".ts" file as TypeScript file.

I have created a file named `confirmationRequiredRenderer`. Initially I created this file by just creating a text file and then adding a `.ts` at the end of the file name.

[image]

Now, no matter what I do, I cannot associated this file as a TypeScript file type. It thinks it is a text file.

These are the actions I have gone through to fix this problem and nothing has worked:

- rebuild project
- restart IDE
- Invalidate caches
- creating a TS file through the wizard, and then renaming it
- npm build

Any advice on why my IDE is so confused with this file?

Comment: What IDE version do you use? (Help | About) Try to temporarily [disable](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-plugins.html) all third-party plugins and restart. Also, try to right-click on a file, select "Associate with File Type..." and manually associate the file with TypeScript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have created a file named `confirmationRequiredRenderer`. Initially I created this file by just creating a text file and then adding a `.ts` at the end of the file name.

That is the source of the problem: the `confirmationRequiredRenderer` file name is now associated with the Text file type. And it has a "priority" because it's longer/more specific than just default `*.ts`.

You need to go into the IDE Settings/Preferences and remove such a association for more broad `*.ts` to be used instead.

1. Go to `Settings/Preferences | Editor | File Types`
2. Locate `Text` file type there
3. Locate and remove the offending entry -- should be `confirmationRequiredRenderer` or very similar to that.
4. Save the settings, let IDE reindex that file and see how it goes.

If still nothing (pretty unlikely but still possible): it may still have an association in another file type, so may need to check other files types for the same.

[image]

---

**P.S.** Another alternative is to *hard-override the file type for that specific file*. Just right click on the file in the Project View panel and choose the right action (**Override File Type**).

It will work for that specific file but will still be an issue for the file with the same name in another project/another folder. So it's much better to fix the original source of the issue.

Comment: thankyou! lesson learned ; always use IDE wizard to create a file.

Comment: @OliverWatkins When you use `New | File` where you can create ANY file with any extension, just do not forget to provide a file extension there. The IDE simply does not know if you are trying to create TypeScript file or TSX or maybe just JS here. Since the file has no extension, the IDE asks how to treat it (because it will open it right away). And by default it has Text file preselected. At the same time the IDE knows what file you are making when you use `New | TypeScript file` and will add the appropriate file extension automatically.